# Gstreamer record camera to multiple files in real time

Tags: video, gstreamer, video-capture, video-recording

I'm working on an application where I need to capture hours of continuous video, and then later upload specific time windows to a remote machine. Because the video data is large, and this system will be collecting for months, everything has to be compressed.

My first attempt was to use two threads to avoid dropping frames - the first has a very simple pipeline with no compression, while the second performs the compression. Here is the pipeline I would want to run on the first:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src num-buffers=300 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! filesink location=myFile
```

This command would be run in a loop to capture a sequence of files. Unfortunately, while this should capture 300/30 = 10s of video, it takes 30s to execute. That means I'm losing a huge amount of video before the next iteration of the loop can start.

I looked into splitmuxsink, but get a message that it doesn't exist, even though I have all the plugins installed.

It seems that gstreamer must be powerful enough for me to access the buffered, raw video and select chunks of it to save as the buffer fills, but there aren't any examples with anything close to this that I can find. How would others recommend going about this goal?

Details:
Jetson Tx1
Ubuntu 14.04

**Update**

Several folks suggested the gstreamer element splitmuxsink - I think this would work in general, but my TX1 comes with gstreamer 1.2.4, which predates splitmuxsink. I looked into updating gstreamer and didn't find anything helpful / it would break a bunch of the tools that Nvidia includes for hardware optimization.

I built a python application to try dynamically modifying a gstreamer pipeline, pointing the stream to different filesink (see below). The code runs ok and (usually) creates a series of avi files. There are a couple problems:

1. Even though the event to start a new file triggers every 10s, the videos themselves are only 3s!
2. Occasionally, a file will be saved with no data, and all subsequent files will be empty

Does anyone have any insight into these problems?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import logging

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', "1.0")
gi.require_version('GstBase', "1.0")
gi.require_version('Gtk', "3.0")
#gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')

from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstBase, Gtk, GstVideo, GdkX11

import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Segmenter:
    def __init__(self):
        Gst.init(None)

        self.terminate = False

        # Create gstreamer pipeline
        cmd = "v4l2src ! tee name=tee ! fakesink"
        self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(cmd)

        # Store references to gstreamer objects
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.recordpipe = None

    def run(self):    
        # Initiate main loop
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

        try:
            while not self.terminate:
                print(dt.datetime.now().time())
                # Listen for event messages on the bus
                msg = self.bus.timed_pop_filtered(10 * Gst.SECOND, (Gst.MessageType.EOS | Gst.MessageType.ERROR))

                if msg:
                    if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
                        err, dbg = msg.parse_error()
                        print("ERROR:", msg.src.get_name(), ":", err)
                        if dbg:
                            print("Debug info:", dbg)
                        self.terminate = True

                    elif msg.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
                        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
                        self.terminate = True

                else:
                    # No message - must have reached timeout
                    self.begin_new_file()


        finally:
            # Free up resources
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

    def begin_new_file(self):

        # If recording a file currently, terminate it
        if self.recordpipe is not None:

            # Block new data
            filequeue = self.recordpipe.get_by_name("filequeue")
            filequeue.get_static_pad("src").add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, self.probe_block)

            # Disconnect the recording pipe
            self.pipeline.get_by_name("tee").unlink(self.recordpipe)

            # Send a termination event to trigger the save
            filequeue.get_static_pad("sink").send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())

            # Clear the reference to the pipe
            self.recordpipe = None

        # Create a new file target
        filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"
        print("Recording {}...".format(filename))

        # Create a new pipeline for the new file
        self.recordpipe = Gst.parse_bin_from_description("queue name=filequeue ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location={} sync=False".format(filename), True)
        self.pipeline.add(self.recordpipe)

        # Connect to the main pipe
        self.pipeline.get_by_name("tee").link(self.recordpipe)

        # Start passing data
        self.recordpipe.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    def probe_block(self, pad, buf):
        """ Callback for downstream block """
        print('block.')
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seg = Segmenter()
    seg.run()
```

Comment: `splitmuxsink` is in the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` (plugin `multifile`): https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/armhf/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/filelist

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splitmuxsink element of the gst-plugins-good, but for this you must have gstreamer 1.5 or higher.

In ubuntu 14.04 only the version 1.4 of gstreamer is present.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-splitmuxsink.html

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-multifile.html#plugin-multifile

Comment: Yeah I just found this myself. Unfortunately I'm stuck with 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for using gstreamer in python3 with nvidia TX2 along with splitmuxsink for spliting in segments the recorded video.
Also i have used the callback function for renaming the output segments with the timestamp.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', "1.0")
gi.require_version('GstBase', "1.0")
gi.require_version('Gtk', "3.0")
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')

from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstBase, Gtk, GstVideo, GdkX11

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

import datetime as dt
import time



class config():
     width = 1280
     height = 720
     fps = 50
     flip = 0
     segments_time = 5000000000 # 5 seconds in nano
     camera_type = "csi"
     usb_cam = "video0"
     iframe_interval = 30 # every 30 frames place a keyframe, this is needed to set frame at 4.75 seconds


config()

global ref_stamp
ref_stamp = 0


# global first segment flag 
global first_segment
first_segment = False


def format_location_callback (splitmux, fragment_id):

    global first_segment

    local_frame_t = round(time.time() * 1000)
    timestamp = str(local_frame_t)
    name = str(timestamp) + ".mp4" 

    # first segment is affected by the time needed to open the camera source so it will have around 6 seconds in lenght but the actual recorded frames inside are for 4,5 seconds
    # in this case first segemnt will be saved as test and only the rest are actual segments with the good timestamp
    if first_segment == False:
        name = 'test' 
    first_segment = True
    return str(name)


src = pipeline.get_by_name ('splitmux')
src.connect("format-location", format_location_callback)


pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

#playing = round(time.time() * 1000)
#print("PLAYING: ", playing)

bus = pipeline.get_bus()
msg = bus.pop_filtered(Gst.MessageType.EOS | Gst.MessageType.ERROR)

count = 1 

while True:
    count = count + 1
    print (count)
    time.sleep(1)
    # if 15 seconds passed stop the recording;
    if count == 15 :
        break

# send the end of stream event and then wait in the bottom loop for event to be send 
# throughout the pipeline.
pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())

# wait in the loop until end of stream is reached
while True:
    msg = bus.pop_filtered(Gst.MessageType.EOS | Gst.MessageType.ERROR)
    if msg:
      print("ENTER")
      if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
           err, dbg = msg.parse_error()
           print("ERROR:", msg.src.get_name(), ":", err)
           if dbg:
                print("Debug info:", dbg)
                break


      elif msg.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
                print("End-Of-Stream reached")
                break
    time.sleep(0.1)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

ref_stamp = round(time.time() * 1000)
print("EXIT: ", ref_stamp)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the given example is not working. The `pipeline` definition is missing.